# What will opening multiple instances of same application result into - multiple processes or threads?

Tags: process

What will opening multiple instances of same application result into - multiple processes or threads? 
If you look into windows task manager after opening internet explorer with multiplt tabs you will notice multiple processes.
On the other hand even if you open up multiple instances of a word document, you can see a single process in task manager.

Comment: This is up to the implementation of an application, it is not a system specific detail.

Answer (score 0):

iexplorer creates processes per tab and show all them in one window (UI).
New instance of MSWord talks to the previous instance and hands over the new task to the previous instance and get killed it self keeping a single instance of Word.